# RequireJS correctly loads CodeMirror but UIKit says that it's not defined

Tags: node.js, requirejs, uikit, sails.js, codemirror

I'm using RequireJS in my project to load my JS dependencies.

This is my configuration file:

```
require.config({
    'baseUrl' : '/js',
    'paths' : {
        'angular' : 'dependencies/angular',
        'cm' : 'dependencies/codemirror',
        'marked' : 'dependencies/marked',
        'jquery' : 'dependencies/jquery',
        'sails' : 'dependencies/sails.io',
        'uikit' : 'dependencies/uikit/js/uikit'
    },
    'config' : {
        'uikit' : {
            'base' : 'dependencies/uikit/js'
        }
    },
    'shim' : {
        'angular' : {
            exports : 'angular'
        },
        'cm/lib/codemirror' : {
            exports : 'codemirror'
        },
        'jquery' : {
            exports : 'jquery'
        },
        'sails.io' : {
            deps : ['socket.io'],
            exports : 'io'
        },
        'uikit' : {
            deps : ['jquery', 'cm/lib/codemirror']
        }
    }
});

define([
    'angular',
    'uikit!htmleditor',
    'cm/lib/codemirror',
    'cm/addon/mode/overlay',
    'cm/mode/markdown/markdown',
    'cm/mode/xml/xml',
    'cm/mode/gfm/gfm',
    'marked'
], function(angular, uikit, CodeMirror) {

    var htmleditor = uikit.htmleditor(document.getElementById("formNewArticleTextarea"), {
        markdown : true,
        mode : 'tab'
    })
});
```

The problem is that every time I reload the page the UIKit HTMLEditor addon returns me this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with CodeMirror and Mergely.

Try putting CodeMirror deliberately into global (window) scope at the top of the init function.  See "Add this line" below:

```
define([
    'angular',
    'uikit!htmleditor',
    'cm/lib/codemirror',
    'cm/addon/mode/overlay',
    'cm/mode/markdown/markdown',
    'cm/mode/xml/xml',
    'cm/mode/gfm/gfm',
    'marked'
], function(angular, uikit, CodeMirror) {
    window.CodeMirror = CodeMirror; // <-- Add this line
    var htmleditor = uikit.htmleditor(document.getElementById("formNewArticleTextarea"), {
        markdown : true,
        mode : 'tab'
    })
});
```